# Can't get import requests to work in PyCharm

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, pycharm

I am having trouble getting requests to work in PyCharm.

requests is installed under
/Users/hb/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages, and it appears the list of installed packages in my interpreter (Python 3.8 (base) ~opt/anaconda3/bin/python3.8. It is up to date. The interpreter path to /Users/hb/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages is listed also.

It does not, however, seem to recognize 'import requests'.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda, pip, requests, PyCharm and nothing has worked. It is worthwhile noting that it did briefly work, but I cannot recall what has changed since it stopped.

Comment: In pycharm, go to your settings `ctr`+`alt`+`s` and then go to the Project menu. Inside there click on Python Interpreter. Do you see the packages installed there?

Comment: Yes, it is installed.

Comment: Edit your run configuration in the drop down just to the left of the play and debug buttons. Is the configuration there using the same python setup you just saw in the settings?

Comment: Yes, it is the same

Comment: have you tried quitting pyCharm and opening it again? Also, the inpterpreter path is the path to the python.exe. Is that how you have it set?

Comment: Yes, I have even tried reinstalling it. And yes, the interpreter path is as you say. I now feel like it may be something unrelated to PyCharm, as it is throwing the same error in R studio and Visual Studio Code...